How does Hexaaquanickel(II) show color
I have studied that there must be unpaired electrons in $t_2g$ orbitals so that they can make transition to the eg orbital by absorbing energy from light. But in $\ce{[Ni(H2O)6]^2+}$ $\ce{Ni^2+}$ has $\ce{d^8}$ configuration which implies it can't have unpaired electrons in $t_2g$ orbitals, then how does it show color? Please explain

Welcome to ChemSE! Please find guidance for MathJax / $\mathrm\LaTeX$ as follows and reformat your post - Basics // MathJax and mhchem formatting for equations and chemical formulae // Guidelines on which should be upright / italics

You do not need vacancies in the $t_{2g}$ orbitals to impart color through $d-d$ transition in octahedral complexes. If you have a vacancy in the $e_g$ orbitals a $t_{2g}$ electron can jump up to one of the vacant states; in the case of a nickel(II)  complex the excited electron pairs with its new $e_g$ partner leaving its original $t_{2g}$ partner no longer paired.
But you do need molecular vibrations to perturb the octahedral symmetry, since otherwise the transition is symmetry-forbidden in a strictly octahedral geometry.
